# How to check if a process is suspended? - Not not responding

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# console application to find if there are any OUTLOOK processes which are suspended. Occasionally on our Terminal server, Outlook will lock up on a session and will get stuck as "Suspended" in Task Manager.

I found this code on a website as an example to checking if a notepad process is suspended:

```
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
var isSuspended = proc[0].Threads[0].ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended;
```

I tried this exact code, but the only ThreadStates that are possible are:

```
- Initalized
- Ready
- Running
- Standby
- Terminated
- Transition
- Unknown
- Wait.
```

There isn't one for "Suspended" as far as I can see. Is there an alternative method for checking for suspended processes?

[image: ThreadState Enumeration]

Comment: that happens when the UI thread is blocked. you have to find the ui thread.

Comment: [ThreadState enum has Suspended state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan I thought so too, but I can't see it. http://imglnk.uk/img?i=CTcfpo.png

Comment: This is not a duplicate! The suggested question isn't about suspended processes, it is about not-responding processes which is different. A process can be suspended without being not-respondig.

Comment: Thanks for marking as duplicate without checking. I hate having to spam the same question.

Comment: System.Threading.ThreadState has Suspended - System.Diagnostics.ThreadState does not. I have seen that proc[0].Threads[0].ThreadState is the latter.

Comment: @PaulF I am not using Threading. It doesn't work with that one anyway. I am talking about Windows processes, Artavaazd was wrong.

Comment: @user2924019, are you sure that you look on that type? There are two ThreadState enums: [System.Threading.ThreadState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Diagnostics.ThreadState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.threadstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan Yes I am sure

Comment: @user2924019, System.Diagnostics.ThreadState does not have this state. Let me prepare some solution using WinAPI call to [NtQuerySystemInformation ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx) to get this info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having established that the thread is *waiting* via it's `ThreadState`, you can examine the [`WaitReason`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.waitreason(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `ProcessThread` and see if *that* says it's [`Suspended`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkhtkxxy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Obviously, there are timing issues with performing tests such as these, since the other process is outside of your control.

Comment: I did find that 99% of the processes say "Wait", and I've now added the WaitReason and they all say "UserRequest". I have yet to test with an actual suspended process though.

Comment: @user2924019 - bear in mind, you may have to examine more than one thread. I'm not sure by which logic Task Manager shows "Suspended" since as we're discussing, it's a *thread* property, not a *process* one. Likely to be either "at least one thread is suspended" or "all threads are suspended" .

Comment: I've just tested on a suspended thread, the application crashes as the arguments are out of range on that suspended thread. The ThreadState was actually suspended but my app didn't understand that.

Comment: I used this method of checking if the ThreadState is 'Wait', and if it is, then check if WaitReason is "Suspended".

Comment: One can debug with ProcessExplorer, On the Threads page of the Process of interest, the thread state is displayed at the bottom `Wait: Suspended`. Suspended process has all threads suspended.